# Почему не работают медиазапросы на некоторых компьютерах?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, bootstrap, media-queries

Есть сайт на `wordpress`, где в собственной теме регистрирую стили bootstrap и собственные `style` через файл `functions.php`

```
// регистрируем стили
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_plugin_styles' );

// регистрируем файл стилей и добавляем его в очередь
function register_plugin_styles() {
  wp_register_style( 'bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css' );
  wp_register_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'style' );
}
```

в `style.css` прописаны медиазапросы, причем последовательно он появляется позже `bootstrap.css`

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding: 34px 7px 38px;
    }
@media screen and (min-width: 1310px) and (max-width: 1366px)  {
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding: 34px 15px 38px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1440px) {
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding: 34px 10px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding: 34px 15px;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1680px) {
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding: 34px 20px;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1920px) {
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding: 34px 31px;
    }
}
```

Но вот не могу понять - почему на некоторых компьютерах и ноутбуках медиазапросы срабатывают и через редактор кода видны (ноутбук 15 дюймов), а на некоторых нет, видны только медиазапросы бутстрап (ноутбук 13 - разрешение 1366px, комп с монитором 22 - разрешение 1920px) и соответственно не срабатывают..

на сервисах типа [screenfly](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/) отрабатывает на всех разрешениях.

пробовал убрать `screen` - эффекта не дало

Comment: У вас между `1366px` и `1440px` разрыв `@media`. Зачем вы это сделали?

Comment: @Visman потому что есть и другие медиазапросы, но я решил не загромождать. пусть даже и ставлю
`@media screen and (min-width: 1310px) and (max-width: 1440px)  {}`
сути это абсолютно не меняет..

Comment: Открывайте инструменты разработчика в том браузере на том компе в котором стили @media не срабатываю и смотрите на этом элементе каким стилем перебивается и из какого файла.

Comment: @Visman в том-то и дело, что не перебиваются, а их нет, вообще нет, понимаете, как написал в описании, а берутся вот эти:
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding: 34px 7px 38px;
    }
даже если вручную уменьшать экран или переключаться на `toogle device toolbar`
причем из бутстраповских медиазапросов при этом читает, так что дело не в компах

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наиболее вероятно, что сайт просматривается в масштабе не 100%.

Хром показывает реальные размеры, но страница и медиазапросы на ней срабатывают видят другие размеры. Например, если страница открыта в окне шириной 1000px в масштабе 200%, то её ширина 500px.

Comment: да, вы правы - спасибо! масштаб был 110% на глаз не видно, но разница в отображении уже значитальная

Answer (score -1):

ответ найдет, только почему так - не понимаю. через f12 но ноуте 13 показывает разрешение `1366px` (и всегда раньше так было), но медиа запрос берет между `1200px` и `1310px`, т.е.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {}
```

почему? - вообще не очевидно... вопрос к экспертам

Comment: не путайте разрешение экрана и ширину окна браузера. Даже развёрнутый на весь экран браузер будет иметь ширину = разрешение минус ширина скролла и т. д.

Comment: @alenkins я ничего не путаю. еще смешнее, что на том же компе, но уже в `ie`, а не `chrome` показывает разрешение 1366px, т.е. берет инфу с этого медиазапроса `@media screen and (min-width: 1366px) {}`

Comment: в обоих случаях в браузере есть скролл? или в обоих случаях в браузере нет скролла? что выводит в консоль `console.log(document.body.clientWidth);`?

Comment: @alenkins как подсказали выше - масштаб был 110%, вместо 100